# Codeigniter 2.0.x - Controller subdirectories default controller needs to be in URL

Tags: codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-2

I recently upgraded a site from CodeIgniter 1.7.x to 2.0.3. About the same time someone in my organization requested we add some pages to the site. Underneath a section. In the old version of the site I used some workarounds in the controller to break up a longer URL. But in version 2 I see that I should be able to use subdirectories in the controllers folder to do it in a more proper way. After looking all over the place I've tried all sorts of routing declarations and fiddled with all sorts of things. Hopefully I'm doing something simple, wrong, or perhaps someone has seen a similar issue stemming from the upgrade.

I'm trying to get the URL from something like:

```
/about/locations
```

Which used to work with a controller named about.php. To something more like:

```
/about/social_responsibility/commitment
```

Where `about` is now a aub-directory.

Funny thing is, currently it does sorta work. That second URL displays correctly. However my old pages, that first URL, now do not function... My new structure uses a base.php (default_controller) in the `about` directory. Thus if I write:

```
/about/base/locations
```

It does work. But I thought the whole routing thing (`default controller`) and using subdirectories is supposed to clean the URL up.

My info is as follows...

**Current Routing** (it's changed a bunch over the last few hours)

```
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['about'] = "about/base";
```

**Directories and Files**

```
/controllers/about/base.php
/controllers/about/social_responsibility.php
```

**Chunk of base.php**

```
class Base extends MY_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['parent'] = "About";

    $this->load->model('mnav');
}

public function index()
{

}

public function locations()
{

}
}
```

I also have a `MY_Controller` that extends `CI_Controller`, but all it does is enable FirePHP for me in the development environment.

Anyone have any clues? Or need some more info to help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you still have the 'about' controller? You can't have both the subdirectory and the controller named the same thing.

Comment: Nope. I removed the file after moving its contents over to the `base.php` file in the folder.

Comment: It could be your route. Try '$route['about/(:any)'] = "about/base/$1";'

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps I'm doing somthing fundamentally outside the scope of the feature... Your route sorta fixed things. The pages just going to `about` worked. But it also broke the rest of the directory's paths. `/about/social_responsibility` now throws a 404. The whole sub-directory thing is kinda the point.

Comment: I'm guessing another alternative is regular expressions. But still, this seems like a lot of work for something that's claimed to work out of the box. Perhaps my theory that "something went wrong in the upgrade process" has something to do with it.

Comment: No, I don't think it's the upgrade. I think it's the need for the route. If you remove the route, you should be able to access `/about/base/locations` and `/about/social_responsibility`. However, since you're trying to remove `base`, that's where the issue lies. When you add the route, it's trying to block all other attempts at getting at `/about/...`

Comment: You might take a look at this page: http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/  --  this doesn't necessarily fix your problem, but you might be able to adjust it for your needs.

Comment: I'll take a look even though it's for the earlier, pre-2.0 version of CI. I just upgraded to the 2.1 download that's on the CI site. Everything else seems to still be functional but I still have my issue. The problem seems to stem from the fact that they claim there's a way to have a default controller for a sub directory but nothing accomplishes that.

I'll also try to pour over the Router.php page in the CI source code when I get to work in the morning.

Comment: Wouldn't your default controller need to be "about/base"?

Comment: @landons Nope, that would break the rest of the site. I don't want people going to the homepage to get about/base. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah.  Sorry, I assumed the "base" controller was in the about folder.  It looked odd at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested on my system, with CI 2.0.2 and it seems that the default controller setting works for subdirectories as well, without any other routes.

```
// so in your config file, whatever your default_controller is set to...
// you would just use that as the name of the `base` controller in about

// for example, if your default_controller is 'welcome' 
// in /application/config.php
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';

// then, it should work for the subdirectory where there is a controller 
// named 'welcome'

//  application/controllers/about/base.php
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo "I can be reached with /about";
    }
}
```

So, all you should have to do is remove all of the routes for `about`

```
// remove this
$route['about'] = "about/base";
```

**Important**
This will only work when accessing /about -- anything in additional segments will be looking for additional controllers. So you'd have to think about how you'd like to access the `base` controller (whether or not you name it something else).

Comment: Thanks swatkins. I actually tried that and it didn't work. I just tried again and removed the other files from the about folder (now it's just base.php) and it stil throws the 404 error when loading /about/. The URL just changes to /about/index and throws the error. 

Guess I have to start pulling out my code to see if something I added to 1.7.x is screwing it up. =/

Comment: I was successful in getting this to work in a default install. But it seems it's not smart enough to handle what exactly I was doing. When adding more methods to base.php they fail. It seems I'd need to move things like /about/locations to their own controllers.

Comment: Well, I think it's working as expected. The default controller setting only works for the index method, and not any others - whether that's in a subdirectory or not. You have some specific and customized requirements, and so you'd have to customize the default functionality. You're going to have to use some regular expressions or customized routes to do what you want.

Comment: Agreed. Now I'm just wondering if I can make it smarter. ;-) Seriously though, I can live with it, but I can't for the life of me figure out why "index" is being added to the end of my URLs. I'm gonna start moving everything over to a clean install till things start breaking I guess. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Got it. It's a long story but basically I inherited a bunch of sloppy code and in my quest to convert some old pages I had to create some odd redirects in PHP. One of those directly affected the about section. I'll have to come up with a cleaner solution for that, but now things are working within CI at least. Naturally I made this all a lot more difficult than it had to be. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that /about/locations is looking for an actual "locations" controller in your about folder, rather than being the method for your base controller.  As far as CI knows, you're trying to execute one of two functions:

1. About controller's "locations" method
2. about/Locations controller's index method (obviously doesn't exist)

It follows that any 3-segment or greater URI will work with this scheme, but 2-segment URI's will confuse it.  I don't think letting CI fallback to the default controller is going to work here. Try this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['([^\/]*)'] = '$1/base';
$route['([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)'] = '$1/base/$2';
```

Comment: I tested it and while it works for the about section (solving the multiple extra controllers) but it's also too greedy and stopped the other sections of the site from working. Thanks for your help! swatkins path worked out better for me.

Comment: No problem.  Just make sure you don't defeat the purpose of route matching and the default functionality.  Ideally, you wouldn't have to touch the routes file very often, or use the _remap function, except in special cases.  Don't swim upstream ;)